# Barcode equal to UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I've got the deviceToken of my device showing in a UILabel on my iPhone. It's quite long so I can't get all of it on the screen. Is there any way to generate a barcode or QR code on the same page equal to the UILabel and show it in my XIB file?

Thanks

Ed

Comment: what does QR Code has to do with displaying the token in a label?

Comment: I guess he wants to display the device token as a QR code because it's too long to fit in a label.

Comment: I need the QR code to be equal to the value of the UILabel, so if the UILabel is displaying A1b2C3 I want the QR code to equal A1b2C3 when scanned

Comment: Read my answer, just call [QRGenerator generateQRCode:yourlabel.text];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create an imageView on your Xib to set the QRCode image on it.

Here is a good code to generate QRCode. I recommend creating a class QRGenerator

Your QRGenerator.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface QRGenerator : NSObject

+ (UIImage *)generateQRCode:(NSString *)string;

+ (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image withQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality rate:(CGFloat)rate;

@end
```

Your QRGenerator.m

```
#import "QRGenerator.h"

@implementation QRGenerator

+ (UIImage *)generateQRCode:(NSString *)string
{
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIQRCodeGenerator"];

    //    NSLog(@"filterAttributes:%@", filter.attributes);

    [filter setDefaults];

    NSData *data = [passportCode dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [filter setValue:data forKey:@"inputMessage"];

    CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:outputImage
                                       fromRect:[outputImage extent]];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage
                                         scale:1.
                                   orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

    // Resize without interpolating
    UIImage *resized = [self resizeImage:image
                             withQuality:kCGInterpolationNone
                                    rate:8.0];

    CGImageRelease(cgImage);

    return resized;
}

+ (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image
             withQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality
                    rate:(CGFloat)rate
{
    UIImage *resized = nil;
    CGFloat width = image.size.width * rate;
    CGFloat height = image.size.height * rate;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, height));
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, quality);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
    resized = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return resized;
}


@end
```

Comment: Where do I put the [QRGenerator generateQRCode:yourlabel.text]; ? Quite a novice here!

Comment: Call it on you image view's image property. Also replace `passportCode` with `string`.

Comment: Personally I would add a `CGFloat edge` parameter to `generateQRCode` and resize the generated `UIImage` by a rate of `edge / image.size.width` to easily match the `UIImageView` size where we're going to display it. Assuming that width and height are equal in a QR code.

Comment: @Desdenova Where do I find the image view's image property?

Comment: @EdG you have to add an `UIImageView` to your XIB and then set its `image` property to the `UIImage` object the `generateQRCode` function returns.

Comment: @keeshux I know it is annoying but do you think you would be able to produce some quick screenshots for me? I don't understand half of that comment!

Comment: Can you just explain how to do it please? I know how to display an image in a XIB but in my image property, all I get is my png's

Comment: @edg I think it is probably a better idea for you to go with the basics, try getting some books with tutorial so you can understand the basics of the language, as well as how xcode works and also the interface builder.

Comment: I know I need to learn the language, but I am kind of holding off for Swift. Anyway, I need to modify this app and get a QR code appearing. Can anyone give some quick, yet helpful, words of advice please?

Comment: As I said before, create a new class called QRGenerator. After that, on your .xib or storyboard you should add a UIImageView. Just drag and drop from the right menu. Create the IBOutlet property on the UIViewController that you want the qrcode to be and the assign the image generated to the imageview like this: ```[self.myImageView setImage:[QRGenerator generateQRCode:self.myLabel.text]]```

Comment: And dont forget to import the the QRGenerator class like ```#import "QRGenerator.h"```

Comment: Ok cool thanks. In that bit of code you've put above, is the only part I need to change the myLabel.text part? Because I have a load of errors!

Comment: You have to create an IBOutlet property for your UIImage as well and call it myImageView, then connect this IBOutlet on your XIB

Comment: @André Cytryn Most of the errors are gone now, I just have this left. This is my ViewController.h (for this plugin anyway!) - does it look right? https://www.dropbox.com/s/kh9a3w83v2ezzd4/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-02%20at%2022.29.44.png?dl=0

Comment: remove the self before the lblDeviceToken.text, create a ```IBOutlet UIImageView *deviceTokenImageView``` and connect on XIB just like you did with the label

Comment: @André Cytryn Xcode just doesn't like me! I've sorted that one out. Now, it is telling me that "lblDeviceToken is an undeclared identifier, did you mean 'EG_deviceToken'?"

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kj9kv9fnv70xkb8/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-02%20at%2022.42.06.png?dl=0 Expanded the problems

Comment: @scord That can't offend me, I know I know nothing about it... I mostly use a CMS to build apps

Comment: @scord Thanks for the info - it now opens without any errors. However, when I try to get to the screen with the QR code on it, I get a SIGBART. It happened earlier when I added a UIImageView so what can I be doing wrong there?

Comment: To everyone. I'd just like to thank you all that helped as I now have it working. It took a while but it is now all good! I know I was a pain to work with but thanks for continuing to help!

Comment: @EdG sorry for being away and not answering your questions but I am glad I could help and you figured it out.